# Swift Web Browser

Tags: swift, browser, nsurl, ibaction

***I am extremely new to swift, and have no experience with objective-C, only partial C++.***

I am trying to create a simple web browser with swift, this is the following code I have:

```
import UIKit

import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet var containerView: UIView!

    var webView: WKWebView?

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        self.webView = WKWebView()
        self.view = self.webView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        var url = NSURL(string: "https://www.duckduckgo.com/")
        var req = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        self.webView!.loadRequest(req)
    }

    @IBAction func Searchresult(sender: AnyObject) {
        url = NSURL(string: "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=\(sender)")
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

Supposedly *XCode* says `Use of unresolved identifier URL` with `@IBAction func` Searchresult.

Once again I am greatly sorry if there is an obvious fix, I am extremely tired and not good at swift.

Comment: Watch this youtube video, https://youtu.be/XWhcnIxrtMk. This is a series video so you will have to wait for new videos.

Answer (score 0):

at first sight seems that you didn't declare url inside @IBAction, just put `let url = NSURL(string: "https://www.duckduckgo.com/?q=\(sender)")`